# How to siphon a pond?

Tags: cleaning, pond

While building a pond, I accidentally got some dirt at the bottom. If that were a fish tank, I would siphon it out, but the pond is lower than anything else around, so it is impossible to get the end of the siphon anywhere lower. Is there a way to still siphon out the dirt from the bottom of a pond?

Answer (score 2):

I use a sump pump. After awhile and the pond is full of leaves,twigs and other debris I get in with a spring rake ( rubber liner )and rake up the stuff so that is does not plug up the sump pump. Right now the water lilies have their roots all through the debris so I will wait until fall.

Answer (score 2):

I think your best option is to get a pond vacuum, it is a good investment for you to get rid of the soil in your pond.

A pond vacuum will save you a lot of work cleaning the bottom of your pond each year, so it is a long term investment.

Renting a pond vacuum is an option in some places, so you might take a look at what possibilities exist in your area for this.